# Spring Boot Controller Test wrongly returning status code 200 instead of 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im currently working on a Spring Boot Rest API.
I have a UserAdministrationController for managing users (adding, removing, editing).

In order to secure all related endpoints, I configure my App in the following way:

```
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }


And for testing purposes I set up in-memory users:

@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails user2 = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername("admin")
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,user2);
    }
```

Additionally, I use @PreAuthorize for all my controller methods like that:

```
 @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> editUser(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody User newUser) {
        User updatedUser = userAdministrationService.editUser(id, newUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedUser);
    }
```

Now I want to test this endpoint and essentially I wanna see that whenever someone calls the endpoint without authorization, a 401 or 403.
My test looks as follows:

```
@Test
    @WithMockUser("USER")
    void editUserTest() throws Exception {
        User modifiedUser = new User("lisa1", "pw", "email@test-mail.com");
        Mockito.when(userAdministrationService.getUserById(modifiedUser.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(modifiedUser));

        modifiedUser.setId("randomId");
        modifiedUser.setRole(Role.ROLE_USER);

        mockMvc.perform(put("/users/{id}", "randomId").with(user("user").roles("USER")).with(csrf()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(modifiedUser))).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
```

So I kinda expect that when using the "USER" Role, I should receive the 403, but in that case I receive status 200.
This is the output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /users/randomId
       Parameters = {_csrf=[qS2FHI3G9z0WNlpkAdOU-q-iy3tBmukEaUsWQFiv5Qle90x-yx-1L-j3lVk7BmlRYv6gy5yX5kIirN8pUXkjcj2fhDhtzi5H]}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"198"]
             Body = {"email":"email@test-mail.com","password":"pw","username":"lisa1","role":"ROLE_USER","id":"randomId","enabled":false,"accountNonExpired":false,"credentialsNonExpired":false,"accountNonLocked":false}
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.server.controller.UserAdministrationController
           Method = com.example.server.controller.UserAdministrationController#editUser(String, User)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<403> but was:<200>
Expected :403
Actual   :200
```

So this is my setup and for others tests it all works as expected, but Im not really sure whats wrong with my editUserTest.

I already tried to check wether the securitycontext returns an authorzied ROLE but it was correctly set to USER so it should still return 403, not 200.

In Postman its the same. Im using Basic auth with the in-memory "user" and it still authenticates me.

So right now Im kinda out of ideas. Anyone has a clue?
Thanks a lot in advance and in cases more info is needed, let me know (still new to the whole stackoverflow thingy)

Comment: Everything has been solved. Apparently I was too blind to see I was missing the securityFilterChain Bean ...... beginners mistake